# What can I do to prevent a growl message from appearing if user clicks the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

User has some tabular data in which they can edit. The edit is made and the user receives a growl-type alert indicated the successful action. The user proceeds with another edit and then changes their mind and clicks the back button. The user sees the message from the previous change and it makes the user think they just inadvertently made a change.

The status (e.g. success or fail) is passed from the action page (where the edits were saved) through the URL along with the msg (e.g. your changes have been saved). The URL looks like this if this helps make this more clear:

```
 http://www.domain.com/admin/profile/user/?status=success&msg=The%profile%20has%20been%20successfully%20saved
```

If the user simply refreshes the page, the same growl message will be displayed.

The users are finding this confusing when they cancel out of an edit, they think it actually happened.

What can I do to provide a better UX so the growl message only displays once?

I'm using ColdFusion if that helps.

Comment: Set a flag in session and delete it after displaying the page.

Comment: Just to repeat what I heard you say, set the flag on the action page and then delete it on the landing page (page with the tabular data). If this is correct, why do I over complicate things!!!  :)

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes you're too deep in the work to notice the easier path. Happens to all of us.

Comment: If you'll put your comment in as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the rope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an update should be triggered set a flag.

```
<!--- update code --->
<cfset session.update = true>
```

Then when you display the message update the session flag

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session, 'update') AND session.update>
  <!--- display message --->
  <cfset session.update = false>
</cfif>
```